# Change Text of Individual labels on map ( OpenLayers )

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3, openlayers-6, angular-openlayers

I want to change the text of a place on **OpenLayers** map, it needs to be changed from **Persian Gulf** to **Arabian Gulf**

I tried to see if there is any way I can make this change using the OpenLayers API documentation and found no luck.

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/

Following is the map location

[image]

Following is code :

```
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/Vector';

....


vectorSource = new VectorSource({
    // url: '/assets/data/countries.geojson',
    url: '/assets/data/countries.json',
    format: new GeoJSON()
  });
  

  mapLayer = new VectorLayer({
    source: this.vectorSource,
    declutter: true
  });

 
  markerLayer = new VectorLayer({
    source: new VectorSource({}),
    style: this.mapStyle
  });

  linesLayer = new VectorLayer({
    source: new VectorSource({}),
    style: this.lineStyle
  });
....
```

Is there any way to change this? I am still going through the **OpenLayers API** to find if there is anyway.

Comment: Please share your code, not the resulting map. Because the answer depends on what kind of layers and sources you are using to create the map. Also, to avoid downvotes, if I were you, I'd rephrase the question to ask more generally for a way to change the text of individual labels.

Comment: Thank you Ahocevar, I have changed the title to generic, will also put in my code

Comment: I have added my code @ahocevar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change labels on a `TileLayer` with the OpenLayers API, because the map image is provided as png images that OpenLayers renders as it receives them.

If your layer were a `VectorTileLayer`, you'd have access to the feature attributes, and could modify their values.

If you continue using a `TileLayer` with data from Mapbox, as you currently do, you could create a custom style using Mapbox Studio, where you could change labels as part of the style.

Comment: No we are using VectorTile Layer only, let me put that code

Comment: The edited code does not match the screenshot any more, and the new code uses a Vector layer, not a VectorTile layer.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this, this can be achieved by editing the map style in https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio/ ( MapBox Studio ), OpenLayers has nothing to do with the content of your map.

I created a custom style and integrated the URL into our app, then everything was just fine.